# If no results for {categories}

Tags: categories, no-results

Is there a way to display a fallback snippet if a {categories show_group='xy'}-Tag is empty / a entry does not have a category?

The example…

```
<p>Category: {categories show_group='xy' backspace='2'}<a href='#'>{category_name}</a>, {/categories}</p>
```

… shows …

```
Category:
```

… if there is no linked category for this entry in this category-group. Is there a way to do something like:

```
Category: No categories assigned
```

… or hide «Category: » in the first place with a conditional or something simpler than this kind-of-complicated stuff:

```
{categories show_group='xy' limit='1'}<p>Category: {/categories}{categories show_group='xy' backspace='2'}<a href='#'>{category_name}</a>, {/categories}</p>{categories show_group='xy' limit='1'}</p>{/categories}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have used this, which isn't the most elegant solution, but does work:

```
{if "{categories show_group='xy'}y{/categories}" != ""}
    Category: {categories show_group='xy'} ... {/categories}
{if:else}
    No categories here
{/if}
```

You could also try the [BW Category Count](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/bw-category-count) add-on.

Answer (score 0):

I'd look at the count parameter as a conditional: http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/categories.html#count

```
{categories show_group='xy' backspace='2'}
{if count == "1"}Category:{/if} // If there are any cat's then show the title
<a href='#'>{category_name}</a>,
{/categories}
```

It's late here and the code may not be perfect but you should get the gist :)

Comment: The `{count}` variable isn't available in the variable pair inside the `{exp:channel:entries}` tag. You're referring to the `{exp:channel:categories}` tag here.

Answer (score 0):

Was having the same problem. I wrote a small (free) plugin that will enable you to do just that. Entry id is mandatory and has optional category groups. [Available here](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/jco-entry-catcount).